# Different Result When Insert Data Contain Quote on Localhost and Online MySQL Hosting

Tags: mysql, php

I installed xampp on localhost and insert data contain quote using this php code

```
$content    = htmlentities($_POST['content']);
$content_esc = mysql_real_escape_string($content);
$save = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_post (title,content,date,publish) values('$title_esc','$content_esc','$date','$publish')");
```

The result on localhost website is

```
this is 'example data'
```

The row on database filled with this

```
this is &quot;example data&quot;
```

But using the same code to insert data the result from my hosting provider is different

```
this is \'example data\'
```

The row on database filled with this

```
this is \&quot;example data\&quot;
```

I test my website on localhost, insert post contain quote and it show on page correctly. Then i surprise when i upload on online hosting, insert post and the post page show '\' before the quote.

At this time i replace the '\' with nothing. How to insert the quote so it can show same result on local mysql database and online mysql database ? What is wrong, my php code or my mysql database ?

Comment: can you post the output of this query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%character_set%';` from localhost and online server

Comment: here the output http://pastebin.com/6BmwiuCa

Comment: Provide the result from this query from both servers `SELECT character_set_name FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_schema = "DATABASE" AND table_name = "tbl_post" AND column_name = "content";` Change `table_schema = "DATABASE"` to your database name

Comment: Please also run `SHOW CREATE DATABASE dbname;` for every database on the Local Server and the Remote Server.

Answer (score 2):

Looks PHP issue, I bet you have Magic Quotes turned off on local (good!) whereas your hosting privider has turned them on - http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php.
When they're turned on it's the same like if you'd write:

```
$content    = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['content']) );//HERE: addslashes is basically the same like your mysql_real_escape_string() - this means contents of $_POST get escaped automatically
$content_esc = mysql_real_escape_string($content);
$save = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_post (title,content,date,publish) values('$title_esc','$content_esc','$date','$publish')");
```

I also guess that next time you're better asking such a question on StackOverflow instead;)